# angular4 vendor and main .js file size after aot compilation

Tags: angular, compilation

MAin.bundle and vendor.bundle size is very large,

How the file size can be reduced as it is causing slow app loading

Comment: IS ther any way to find unused imports in the app (Insome cases the specific import can reduce the size where the complete import of library make the overall bundle size heavy) finding such files manually will be very tedious , is there any tool to analyze all these ?)

Answer (score 0):

I use:

`ionic cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs`

Comment: I am using ng build --aot

Comment: Sorry, I thought you was talking about Ionic.

Comment: The main and vendor file will be very large depending the app size. What you can do to reduce the main file is to use lazy loading with every module of you app. But the size difference is not going to be so big. I use in angular projects this command: ng build -prod . The prod flag use aot by default